# Classifying broader, functional symmetries

Tags: functional-analysis, symmetry

If $f(x) = f(-x),$ then the function is said to be symmetric, so the transformation $x \rightarrow -x$ is an example of a symmetry.

Trig functions like $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ satisfy the property that $f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$ and so their manifold remains invariant under shifting. I don't know if this is technically a "symmetry" or not, but if it is, I'd classify it as a shift symmetry.

Is there a name for if/when $f(ax) = f(x),$ for some fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

More generally, is there an area of math that studies functional relationships of the form $f(g(x)) = f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

A symmetry of the form $f(ax) = f(x)$ is called a scaling symmetry, or sometimes a dilation or dilatation; generally, a function satisfying $f(ax) = a^k f(x)$ for *all* scalars $a$ and some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is called [homogeneous of degree $k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).

The study of symmetry is called [group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) and the study of functions invariant under groups of symmetries is called [invariant theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory). This is an old classical branch of mathematics and many things are known. Closely related are [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) and [harmonic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_analysis), although really the basic idea is so fundamental it appears in all sorts of other places as well. For example [modular forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form) are certain special functions satisfying an almost-symmetry with respect to a group called the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group), and they are quite important in number theory.